# HTML PHP Form Processing; Variable

Tags: php

I'm a newbie learning and trying to understand how html forms and php processing works.

Came across this pair of examples:

HTML FORM:

```
<html>
<body>

  <form action="hello-web.php" method="GET">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="yourName" size="24">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP PROCESSOR:

```
<?php
$fname = $_GET["yourName"];

echo "Hello $fname!";
?>
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:
Hello Entered/Example Name!

QUESTION:
When I try to change the variable **"yourName"** (on BOTH HTML and PHP files) to, for example **"typeName"** , the entered name on the form does not show up.

In other words, the output becomes just: Hello  !

Is "yourName" a standard php or html variable? Can it not be changed to what ever you want it to be?

Better yet, how exactly does the form process data?

---

Here is my altered code that won't output the entered name (I posted here as an answer because all the codes shows up as a continuous line, like a paragraph, when I paste as a comment to your answer:

HTML FORM(altered--typeName):

```
<html>
<body>

  <form action="hello-web.php" method="GET">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="typeName" size="24">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP PRCESSOR (altered--typeName):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$fname = $_GET["typeName"];

echo "Hello $fname!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you change both it should work, probably just a typo

Comment: If I enter "Washington", here's the url: http://localhost:8888/lessons/hello-web.php?yourName=Washington

Comment: But output is still just : Hello  !

Comment: Just to make sure, is the name of your second file exactly the same as the file name in `<form action="">`? If not, and `<form action="">` is calling some random php file, that would explain why you aren't seeing the first name being output to the screen.

Comment: Why does it still show yourName on the url? I've saved the file--even closed it and re-open, now with "typeName".

Comment: Woah! Thanks. I renamed both files and the corresponding values in <form action=""> and it worked. Although I'm still wondering why, as you suggested, it may have been calling another php file. And why did "yourName" keep showing up in the url when I totally eliminated/changed all of of them? Hmmm. By the way, I'm using MAMP on Lion--if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what data is available to you from the submitted form by outputting the entire array. Since your form method is `GET`, the following will show you all that was submitted:

```
var_dump( $_GET );
```

From this, you can see what the variable names should be in your PHP script.

```
Array
(
  [YourName] => Jonathan
)
```

Anytime you come across a disconnect between what is being submitted, and what you're expecting, check `$_GET` (or if your method is `POST`, you would check `$_POST`).

For instance, if I were trying the following:

```
echo $_GET["yourName"]; // nothing output to the screen
```

I could refer to the array contents printed above and see that the correct key is "YourName":

```
echo $_GET["YourName"]; // Jonathan
```

Comment: +1 for "teaching how to fish" instead of just speculating at possible issues.

Comment: Which part of the code--or in what line--should I place var_dump($_GET)? Can this also apply to $fname  ?

Comment: @user1373564 You can put `var_dump( $_GET )` at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET["yourName"];` Contains a value based off of the input of the form field. It's a php superglobal https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

It sounds like you're changing the html form, but your not entering a value through the form. Therefore, `$_GET["yourName"];` is empty